# Insert string on every level of braces within a string

Tags: javascript, regex, graphql

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with an algorithm (in JS) to help insert a string, in this case "id" onto every level of brackets within another string. For example, if I have the following string:

`"{id name sub1 { attr sub2 { val key code } id } suba { val key subb { subc { key} } } }"`

I'd like to convert it to look like:

`"{id name sub1 { attr sub2 { val key code } id } suba { id val key subb { id subc { id key} } } }"`

Where after conversion, every level of brackets has an id field.

Please ask if any clarifications are needed. Thanks!

EDIT: Whoops! Sorry I forgot to add an important stipulation: 
If a subset inside brackets already has a "code" value defined, then we shouldn't add an id to that level/subset. This can be seen in the above result where sub2 doesn't have an `id` field in the converted result.

Besides not wanting ids where there are already codes, the position of the ID field is not important inside the brackets so long as they don't come between the opening bracket and the word immediately before the opening bracket. Aka: this conversion would NOT be good:

`{name sub { val key}} --> {name sub id { val key id}}`

Comment: Is the position of `id` inside a pair of brackets important?

Comment: Is it important that "id" is inserted at the opening or closing braces ? Is "id" a fixed string ? Is it feasible in your task to program this as a recursive function ? ( select all text within outer quotes, feed it as input to the same  question until no more braces detected)

Comment: @Éric I made an important edit to the question and also explained the id positioning rules. @B Aerts the id insertion position does not matter except for where explained above. And yes, we have access to recursive functions. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stack-based algorithm approach to solve this problem. Please find the below code for this problem.

```js
function addId(str) {
  let stack = [];
  let word = "";
  let newString = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let char = str[i];

    if (char === " ") word = "";
    else if (char === "{") stack.push({
      found: false
    });
    else if (char === "}") {
      let popChar = stack.pop();
      if (popChar["found"] === false) char = (str[i - 1] === " " ? "id " : " id ") + char;
    } else {
      word += char;
      if (word === "id" || word === "code") stack[stack.length - 1]["found"] = true;
    }
    newString += char;
  }
  return newString;
}



const a = "{ name sub1 { attr sub2 { val key code }  } suba { val key subb { subc { key} } } }"

const newA = addId(a)
console.log(newA)
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent work @user3846235, I unfortunately didn't specify all the constraints well enough. I made an edit to the original question if you'd be so kind as to give it another crack.

Comment: I made an edit in my answer according to the requirement

Answer (score 1):

> **Edit:** This answer was OK until the OP added the following condition: *only add missing `id` to a set or subset if it does not include `code`*.

If the position of `id` is not relevant (except the fact that it must not be inserted just before an opening curly bracket):

```
// Pure JS
var $string = "{id name sub1 { attr code sub2 { val key } id  } suba { val key subb { subc { key} } } }";
$string = $string.replace(/\bid\b */g, "").replace(/{/g, "{ id ");
alert($string);
```

Result: `{ id name sub1 { id  attr code sub2 { id  val key } } suba { id  val key subb { id  subc { id  key} } } }`

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ft2jhpq0/2/

Best regards

Comment: please see above for new info I added. Thank you very much!

Comment: @majorBummer, OK, I posted a new answer to take your extra condition into account. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Considering the condition added by the OP (*only add missing `id` to a set or subset if it does not include `code`*), I dropped the logic used in my previous answer and now propose to proceed like this:

1. Convert the string into a Javascript object.
2. Parse the object and modify it.
3. Convert the object back to a string.

With this code:

```js
// Pure JS
const string = "{id name sub1 { attr sub2 { val key code } id } suba { val key subb { subc { key} } } }";

// Start of procedure
//// A function for later
function parseAndModifyObj(obj) {
 let add_id = true, obj_keys = Object.keys(obj);
 for (let k of obj_keys) {
  if (typeof obj[k] === "string" && ["code", "id"].includes(obj[k])) add_id = false;
  else if (typeof obj[k] === "object") obj[k] = parseAndModifyObj(obj[k]);
 } 
 if (add_id) obj.id = "id";
 return obj;
}
//// 1. Convert the string into a Javascript object (dummy property names are added if needed)
var string_as_obj = string.replace(/(\b\w+\b)(?!\s*\{)/g, "%KEY%:\"$1\"").replace(/(\"|})\s+(?=%|\w)/g, "$1, ").replace(/(\w)\s*{/g, "$1:\{");
for (let i = 1; string_as_obj.match(/%KEY%/g); i++) string_as_obj = string_as_obj.replace("%KEY%", i);
eval("string_as_obj = " + string_as_obj);
//// 2. Parse the object and modify it, with the function defined above
string_as_obj = parseAndModifyObj(string_as_obj);
//// 3. Convert the Javascript object back into a string
new_string = JSON.stringify(string_as_obj).replace(/\"/g, "").replace(/\w+:(?!\{)/g, "").replace(/,|:/g, " ");
// End of procedure

console.log("Input string:\n" + string + "\n\n");
console.log("Output string:\n" + new_string + "\n\n");
```

Result: `{id name sub1 {attr id sub2 {val key code}} suba {val key subb {subc {key id} id} id}}`

Best regards